# Problem with "rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune"

Tags: package-management

I have problem with software installation on my ubuntu(12.04). Whenever I want use ubuntu  software center popup show up with information that "Items cannot be installed or removed..." and option cancel and repair(repair not resolving problem).

Log is following

```
installArchives() failed: dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Version of rhythmbox on system is 2.96-0ubuntu4.3.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune
Error in function: 
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Version of rhythmbox on system is 2.96-0ubuntu4.3.
dpkg: error processing rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

I've tried some solution like this:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12093363#post12093363

But still when im executing these commands error with rhythymbox plugin appear.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune:
 rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune depends on rhythmbox (= 2.96-0ubuntu4.2); however:
  Version of rhythmbox on system is 2.96-0ubuntu4.3.
```

This problem blocking me installing some required software, I will appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with the mirror. Both packages `rhythmbox` and `rhythmbox-plugin-magnatune` version 2.96-0ubuntu4.3 are available in the repositories as can be seen [in the Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rhythmbox/2.96-0ubuntu4.3) page. For some reason or another the mirror doesn't have properly synced. You should update your lists:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rhythmbox
```

Or change to another mirror.